# Can I pass COM interface on WCF named pipe?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, com, named-pipes

Can I pass COM interface on WCF named pipe?

I have the following COM interface:

```
[CoClass(typeof(ConfigViewerClass))]
[Guid("E51C677A-163B-11D4-AFE4-00902743BD1F")]
public interface ConfigViewer : IConfigViewer{}
```

When I try to pass it as return type in my WCF I'm getting the following error:

> There was an error reading from the pipe: The pipe has been ended.
>   (109, 0x6d).

Why is this?

I tried the following but failed:

1. Change TransferMode to Streaming.
2. Encapsulate the COM interface as `[DataMember]` inside c# class that define as `[DataContract]`
3. Pass empty instace of this COM interface (for smaller traffic size).
4. Adding KnownType attribute - Causes compilation error since it COM classes :

> Attribute 'KnownType' is not valid on this declaration type. It is
>   only valid on 'class, struct' declarations.

Thanks!

Comment: Any useful messages from tracer?

Comment: @Reniuz I'm afraid not..

Comment: Added all KnownTypes to your service interface?

Comment: @Reniuz I can't since it COM classes - see my edit on attempt 4.

Comment: I'm not sure what you expect to get out of the other end. An object implementing the interface? How does WCF know how to construct a COM object?

Comment: @GazTheDestroyer It has refernce to the same COM type library so the WCF reconziged the object.

Answer (score 0):

The error message means that when your client-side channel stack is trying to read the response from the pipe, it finds that the pipe instance has been closed already.

You could confirm this by configuring WCF Tracing on the service side and looking at what exceptions are being raised, but I imagine that the service-side channel stack is failing (and so aborting the pipe connection) when it tries to serialize the instance your service is providing as the return value: it will be discovering that the object's concrete type is an RCW, which it has no idea how to serialize.

I don't believe it is possible to use a COM interface type in a WCF service operation's parameters or return values.

If your COM coclass exposes interfaces/methods which support serializing and deserializng the state of an instance of the coclass, you may be able to work around this by defining a pure .NET type wrapping the ConfigViewer and then implementing `ISerializable` or `IXmlSerializable` on the wrapper type by hand, using the COM methods for serializing and deserializing the object state. This wrapper type would then be used in the service operation signature, and would need to be in an assembly deployed both to server and clients.